# Input voltage on transformer

Tags: voltage, transformer, mains, replacement, markings

I’m replacing a transformer on hot tub. Markings on original were obliterated from rust. New transformer is marked as follows. 0 v blk wire, 115 v white wire, 230v red wire. The transformer receives power from a plug on a pc board. I’ve measure the voltage on the board as follows. Blk wire Socket 110v, 0 white wire socket 110v red wire socket. My question is do these corresponding board voltages need to match the transformer input voltages? I was reassured this is the correct transformer.

[image: transformer label]

[image][image][image]

Comment: Are you thinking that they don't match because you are measuring 110V and the transformer is marked 115V?

Comment: You description of the voltages on the socket is somewhat scrambled - please clarify

Comment: The readings on the board correspond to the USA standard for split-phase 120/240 residential power distribution. The white wire is connected to ground at the breaker panel. I believe that the white source wire should be connected to the black transformer wire, the red source wire to the red transformer wire and the black source wire should be connected to the white transformer wire.

Comment: @CharlesCowie  the "red wire socket" and "black wire socket" could also be at the same potential of 110v. In any case you would usually only wire 2 wires  to the transformer primary, otherwise the tiny transformer would be trying to act as as auto-transformer for the entire house.  In some consumer equipment, three wires would be attached to the PCB only where there was a mix of 115v and 230v. ( also 110v and 220v) on the circuit, e.g where most of the control circuitry operates off 110v, but the heating element is 220v, so the whole unit plugs into just a 220v outlet.

Comment: @BobT, I agree that only 2 wires would usually be connected to the primary, but I don't think there is any problem with grounding the center point of a center-tapped transformer.

Comment: Hi Steve, Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange! Could you please furnish the colours of the wires terminated on the plugs in the original transformer?

Comment: I  would think grounding the centre tap would only be a  good idea on the power pole outside. Grounding the centre tap on a small transformer inside a house would inject very large currents into the ground wire proportional to differences in line voltage divided by transformer leakage inductance, that would hopefully trip the RCD or GFCI.. The earth terminal is there for protection purposes, not to connect power devices to.

Comment: @BobT, I am not suggesting literally grounding the neutral, but that the grounding through the neutral by connecting the neutral there should not be problematic. It seems to me that the only potential difficulty would be due to imbalance between the two 120V circuits and that shouldn't be significant. On the other hand, I don't know any reason for simply not connecting the neutral if there is nothing else connected between the transformer and the connection point.

Comment: Hello again, okay I’m pretty “green” at this but I’ll attempt to add more helpful info. Maybe some photos too. Old transformer had three wires from connector at board to primary, red , black and white. New transformer has Two wires from connector to primary, red , black, but the white is capped off, not inserted in connector. So if I remove the old connector to use on new transformer can I assume the white wire would be spliced to the white wire on the new transformer?  Also where the transformer plugs into the socket on board, should those voltages match what’s printed on the transformer?

Comment: _" I’ve measure the voltage on the board as follows. Blk wire Socket 110v, 0 white wire socket 110v red wire socket"_ - what voltage do you measure between the black and red wires? _"New transformer has Two wires from connector to primary, red , black, but the white is capped off, not inserted in connector."_ - you mean the transformer has 3 wires, but the white isn't connected? Please show a photo of the new transformer wires and connector.

Comment: Yes Bruce, the new transformer has three wires. The re and black which are inserted in the connector and then the white which is not inserted but has a plastic cap or cover on it. The voltage on the board where the transformer plugs in measures 110 v on the pins  that would mate with the red and black wire. I will try to post pictures.